# How does Django determine if an uploaded image is valid?

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to add images to my models in my Django app.

models.py

```
class ImageMain(models.Model):
"""This is the Main Image of the product"""
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='products')
```

In development mode, every time I try to upload the image via Django admin, I keep getting:

```
Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image.
```

The jpg I'm trying to upload can be viewed with os X Preview so it would seem to be valid.

It seems the problem is Python Imaging Library doesn't recognize it as an image. Why would that be happening with a valid image?

PIL is installed, verified via the Django shell.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to Django's source code. Those three lines are responsible for verifying images:

```
from PIL import Image
trial_image = Image.open(file)
trial_image.verify()
```

The image type could be unsupported by PIL. Check the list of supported formats [here](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/index.htm)

Comment: The image is a jpeg and according to the list is installed.

Comment: Try to open the image in PIL and see what you get. The image might be indeed corrupted even if you can view it in os X Preview

Comment: IOError: decoder jpeg not available
I've got PIL release 1.1.6

I'm going to try to install libjpeg.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try uploading image format like gif or png? It might be that your PIL was not built with the jpeg lib properly.  I had a similar issue with Django on Ubuntu.  If you have ever seen the error message `decoder jpeg not available`, check this [link](http://effbot.org/zone/pil-decoder-jpeg-not-available.htm).  Relevant line from the link:

```
$ cd libImaging
$ ./configure --with-jpeg=/somelib/lib --with-zlib=/somelib/lib
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the Django source, in `django/forms/fields.py`, in the `ImageField` class. Django actually does use PIL to determine when an image is valid.